# Why is the styling property producing different results when called in two different ways?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to apply a 'flexDirection' property of 'row' to my layout, but the output is different depending on the method used. I want to understand why react native is behaving in such a way.

I've tried playing around with different properties to achieve the required result.

**Keypad.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import Keys from './Keys';

import styles from './styles';

let rows = [];
let nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let row = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    row.push(<Keys number={nums[i][j]} />);
  }
  rows.push(<View style={"this is where the problem occurs"}>{row}</View>);
}

const Keypad = () => <View>{rows}</View>;

export default Keypad;
```

**Keys.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';

const Keys = ({ number }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={styles.number}>{number}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

export default Keys;
```

**styles.js**

```
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

export default EStyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  number: {
    fontSize: 40
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
});
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

import TestScreen from './screens/TestScreen';

EStyleSheet.build({
  // WelcomePage
  $white: '#FFFFFF',
  $black: '#000000',
  $getStartedBlue: '#40A5D6',
  $welcomeMessage: '#767676',

  // VerificationPage
  $primaryBackground: '#C3C3C3',
  $secondBackground: '#40A5D6',
  $numbers: '#352641',
  $backspace: '#9599B3',
  $nextButton: '#0062CC'

  // $outline: 1
});

export default () => <TestScreen />;
```

**App.js**

```
import App from './app/index';

export default App;
```

I am expecting numbers in the form of a keypad. I've marked the line in Keypad.js where the problem lies.

When I use:

```
rows.push(<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>{row}</View>);
```

as the styling property I get the required output (a keypad from numbers 1-9).

But when I use:

```
rows.push(<View style={styles.row}>{row}</View>);
```

then all the numbers overlap over one another and appear as a smudge on the screen.

In my understanding, it is just another way to apply the same property, so why is the result different?

Comment: I dont know about the package you are using, but the code should be the same. try to change EStyleSheet with react-native's StyleSheet, to see if there are some differencies

Comment: This actually worked. So it seems it has something to do with the EStyleSheet package. Wonder how to get it working as I am using EStyleSheet throughout the whole project. Thank you for your perspective though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing the important part from the [docs](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet),

> In app entry point call EStyleSheet.build() to actually calculate styles:

You need to add this in `app.js` file,

```
/* app.js */
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

EStyleSheet.build({ // always call EStyleSheet.build() even if you don't use global variables!
  $textColor: '#0275d8'
});
```

Comment: You are right, I have that as my index.js file which I am using as the entry point. I did not share that code here because I didn't think it was relevant. But thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Do share app.js file also.

Comment: My file structure is different and I am using index.js as the entry point, but I also shared the App.js which directs to index.js.

Comment: What is use of App.js then? Give it a try move `EStyleSheet` code to `App.js` file.

Comment: Just a personal preference for the file structure. I'll try that out and see.